# Undefined symbols linking to framework CMake

Tags: c, macos, linker, frameworks, cmake

When compiling/statically linking [a project of mine](https://github.com/syb0rg/pocketsphinx), I get the following error (in this case with OpenAL, I've tried other audio libraries such as PulseAudio and get similar errors):

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_alcCaptureCloseDevice", referenced from:
      _ad_close in libsphinxbase.a(ad_openal.c.o)
  "_alcCaptureOpenDevice", referenced from:
      _ad_open_dev in libsphinxbase.a(ad_openal.c.o)
  "_alcCaptureSamples", referenced from:
      _ad_read in libsphinxbase.a(ad_openal.c.o)
  "_alcCaptureStart", referenced from:
      _ad_start_rec in libsphinxbase.a(ad_openal.c.o)
  "_alcCaptureStop", referenced from:
      _ad_stop_rec in libsphinxbase.a(ad_openal.c.o)
  "_alcGetIntegerv", referenced from:
      _ad_read in libsphinxbase.a(ad_openal.c.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

You can find the `CMakeLists.txt` in the link to the project, but I think the error lies within [its dependency](https://github.com/syb0rg/sphinxbase) (despite it compiling just fine and generating a x86_64 architecture library).  Here is the dependency's main `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
#
# Initial CMake and project setup
#

CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8 FATAL_ERROR)
SET(PROJECT_NAME sphinxbase)
PROJECT(${PROJECT_NAME})

SET(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")
SET_DIRECTORY_PROPERTIES(PROPERTIES EP_PREFIX ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/build-data)

#
# Setup compiler flags
#

if (NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
    message(STATUS "No build type selected, default to Release")
    set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE CACHE Release FORCE)
endif()

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG} -std=gnu11 -O0 -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE} -std=gnu11 -O3")

#
# Final project settings
#
configure_file("${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/sphinx_config.h.in" "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/sphinx_config.h")
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(include)
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(src)
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(test EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)

ADD_LIBRARY(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC
        $<TARGET_OBJECTS:libsphinxad>
        $<TARGET_OBJECTS:fe>
        $<TARGET_OBJECTS:feat>
        $<TARGET_OBJECTS:lm>
        $<TARGET_OBJECTS:util>
        $<TARGET_OBJECTS:sphinx_adtools>
        $<TARGET_OBJECTS:sphinx_cepview>
        $<TARGET_OBJECTS:sphinx_fe>
        $<TARGET_OBJECTS:sphinx_jsgf2fsg>
        $<TARGET_OBJECTS:sphinx_lmtools>
    )

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${PROJECT_NAME} ${LIBS})
```

I'm setting `${LIBS}` in the `libsphinxad` object folder:

```
include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include/sphinxbase)

if (WIN32)
    set(SOURCES ${SOURCES} ad_win32.c)
endif ()

find_package(PulseAudio)
if (PULSEAUDIO_FOUND)
    set(SOURCES ${SOURCES} ad_pulse.c)
    set(LIBS ${PULSEAUDIO_LIBRARIES} CACHE INTERNAL "libs")
endif()

find_package(OSS)
if (OSS_FOUND)
    set(SOURCES ${SOURCES} ad_oss.c )
endif()

find_package(OpenAL)
if (OPENAL_FOUND)
    set(SOURCES ${SOURCES} ad_openal.c)
    set(LIBS ${OPENAL_LIBRARY} CACHE INTERNAL "libs")
    include_directories(${OPENAL_INCLUDE_DIR})
endif()

find_package(ALSA)
if (ALSA_FOUND)
    set(SOURCES ${SOURCES} ad_alsa.c)
    set(LIBS ${ALSA_LIBRARIES} CACHE INTERNAL "libs")
endif()

add_library(libsphinxad OBJECT ${SOURCES})
```

As you can see, I'm linking to the OpenAL framework.  Here is the path that CMake is sending into `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES` that gives the error above:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenAL.framework
```

It looks like I'm doing things correctly, so I'm somewhat confused.  I've tried adding `-framework` flags and adding linking to other libraries such as CoreAudio and Foundation to no avail.  Any suggestion?

---

I have gotten the project to build without error linking to the dynamic library, but for my purposes I need to link the library statically.

Comment: Try using `$(SDKROOT)` ... `/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenAL.framework` ... I think the framework is now located at `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenAL.framework`

Comment: @l'L'l Same problem unfortunately, after verifying I had that framework at that location

Comment: Here's the CMake log generated when I try it with sphinxbase-master: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/07b7688f48fb3926c40b45a15a7131bf. It may or may not be useful...

Comment: @l'L'l If you build that, it should compile correctly (it does for me).  Try building the main project and see if you get the same error I get (link at the top of the question)

Comment: Yep, that's the main project (not pocketsphinx) and the same (or similar) error it looks like. I tried using `autotools` also, and that didn't yield any errors, although i didn't build it since I don't have swig installed.

Comment: Here's the path that `autotools` creates for it's `configure`:   `ad_cppflags="-I$sdkpath/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenAL.framework/Versions/A/Headers/"` — if you want me to post the entire file let me know.

Comment: @l'L'l If you have time, we could try tackling the problem together [in this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43601/khronos-development)

Comment: Can you further reduce your example and make it self-contained?

Comment: @usr1234567 It's more reduced than I think it should be. I'm not even including any code from the problematic project.  A side note (I'm assuming you're the one that downvoted), you should only downvote unclear questions that don't show research effort, or aren't useful.